# IntersectionObserver - transform properties targets the whole SVG animation and not class

Tags: reactjs, animation, svg, transform, intersection-observer

I'm trying to get a svg animation to start when it's in the viewport. It works but when adding `transform properties` the whole svg and not just the targeted class is affected.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as Animation2Svg } from '../assets/animation3.svg';
import './animation2.css';

export const Animation2 = () => {
  const animationRef = useRef();
  const [visibleAnimation, setVisibleAnimation] = useState();
  console.log('visibleAnimation', visibleAnimation);
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      const entry = entries[0];
      setVisibleAnimation(entry.isIntersecting);
      console.log('entry', entry);
    });
    observer.observe(animationRef.current);
    // console.log('animationRef', animationRef.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={animationRef}
      className={`'animation_container' ${visibleAnimation ? 'lamp_fill' : ''}`}
    >
      <svg
        viewBox="0 0 960 960"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <g id="lamp">
          <g id="_12">
            <g id="Group">
              <path
                className="lamp_fill"
                d="M 673.8,268.9 C 670.49,212.31 666.03,147.85 624.05,105.09 605.03,88.927 595.75,88.708 576.1,80.6 534.08,69.765 491.07,82.083 449.66,89.913 382.62,105.67 316.07,123.33 250.11,143.21 201.04,156.23 143.22,156.92 106.41,196.62 76.875,241.04 84.709,297.04 84.201,347.5 86.612,407.39 83.901,468 85.176,528.14 91.427,563.78 86.363,600.74 93.601,636.8 98.899,686.58 100.94,736.75 110.7,786 111.72,829.71 125.29,878.56 165.7,901.7 198.5,924.75 239.5,926.4 278.1,929.56 334.3,923.31 391.34,926.4 447.84,924.66 496.01,923.32 545.09,928.05 592.56,918.66 626.73,907.16 644.69,870.96 647.87,836.92 653.71,790.73 638.83,744.73 638.8,698.8 639.22,658.74 633.25,618.65 640.1,578.7 645.02,533.8 655.02,489.37 657.67,444.12 668.11,386.49 675.47,327.74 673.8,268.9 Z"
              fill="black"
              />
              <!--multiple path elements-->
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And this I the CSS that works (and without transform properties)

```
.lamp_fill {
  transform-box: fill-box;
  fill: transparent;
  animation: turnOn 6s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes turnOn {

  0%,
  30% {
    fill: transparent;
  }

  40%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    fill: #ffb200;
  }
}
```

I have tried to move the `ref` so ut targets the svg directly but to be honest I have no idea how to solve this.

Here is a CodeSandbox to illustrate the problem
https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-tree-xmd32p?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] right here, not externally. [Reduce complexity.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402684/how-to-reduce-complicated-code-on-runnable-code-example-sites-to-a-sensible-stac)

Comment: @ccprog - thank you for your reply :) I tried to do so, but the svg makes the code too long. But I'll add back the code with the svg being imported.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to add some relevant parts of the `<svg>` to your code. Still, I don't think I understand what you want to achieve. What should the animation look like in detail? What should be transformed, what should be recolored?

Comment: Oh, and the `'` apostrophe around `animation_container` - is that a typo? That part is inside the backticks.

Comment: @ccprog, I want to, for example, add a transition to the .lamp_fill without that transition having an impact on the entire svg.  If I would add  ```transform: translateY(-100px);``` to the keyframe, the svg moves up ```100px``` and not only the ```.lamp_fill class```. I am guessing there is a way to make only the target class move? So, to speak plainly, I would like to move only the ```.lamp_fill``` up 100px.

Comment: @ccprog - thank you for checking the svg, how can I see the changes you made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the are two objects with the class `lamp-fill`, and both get animated.

```
<div className={`animation_container ${visibleAnimation ? 'lamp_fill' : ''}`} >
```

and

```
<path className="lamp_fill" d="..." />
```

If you want only the second one to be animated, set the class only there. Like this:

```
<div
  ref={animationRef}
  className='animation_container'
>
  <svg
    viewBox="0 0 960 960"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <g id="lamp">
      <g id="_12">
        <g id="Group">
          <path
            className={visibleAnimation ? "lamp_fill" : ""}
            d="..."
          fill="black"
          />
          <!--multiple path elements-->
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
```